# Reorder Array of Red, Blue and Green balls

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In one of my interviews the interviewer asked me - 
An array of some size contains Red, Blue and Green balls all mixed up randomly. 
like RGBBBRRGGG, where RGB is for Red, Green and Blue.

What is the most optimal way to end up with an array like- RRRRGGGGBBBB
i.e. all R's, all G's and all B's together.

I proposed converting all Red, Blue, Green to their ASCII values and then running the most efficient sorting algorithm on it. 
But he wasn't impressed . Any other more efficient solution to this problem ? with lowest space and time complexity ?

Comment: You will probably get help faster from http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 16):

Simply go through the array and count the occurrence of `R`, `G` and `B` respectively. Then, output the string. Linear time.

Comment: This is the one I'd use. Questions like these are sneaky -- designed to push you in a direction most programmers are familiar with. But that direction does **not** actually offer the most efficient solution for the posed problem.

Comment: Rody: This is sorting (counting sort). OP's familiar idea to select  "the most efficient sorting algorithm" was correct, but imprecise.

Comment: i proposed this solution also, the interviewer from Paypal found it very amusing and said "such a solution even a kid can propose, give me an innovative solution." I think he was looking for the solution on the lines of the Dutch National Flag problem (mentioned by @Blastfurnace ) as one of the answers

Comment: This is simply radix sort with an alphabet of size 3.

Answer (score 9):

The interviewer might have wanted to know if you were familiar with the [Dutch national flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem). It has a simple linear solution. There are `C++` and `Java` examples on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: yeah I think you are right ! because he kept on imploring me to think more innovative for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I may have misunderstood your question

You'd want to convert the RGB value to an HSL value. You'd then know the hue which would tell you the color it's closest to, which sorts out which R/G/B section it belongs in. You can then go further, taking in the hue, saturation and lighting to determined their exact order among each other, relative to the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it could be possible if you can save like that "4R4G4B" to save it efficiently

Answer (score 0):

This problem can easily be done in linear time. To further improve the algorithm, you can create a counter array int[3] and have counter[0], counter[1] and counter[2] count reds, greens, and blues respectively. Therefore you only have to go through the array once.

Another solution that minimize the space complexity is to have 3 pointers: current, rg and gb. The pointer current indicates the array position you're currently looking at and rg and gb is the boundary between red / green and green / blue respectively. Initialize current = 0, rg = -1, gb = n, where n = size of A.

While gb>current
 - if A[i] == R, shift rg by 1 to the right, and replace current with rg
 - else if A[i] == blue, shift fb by 1 to the left, replace current with gb
 - else, do nothing

Space complexity = O(n) because you're not using any additional arrays
Time complexity = O(n), each element is swapped at most once

Answer (score 0):

### Python Solution

```py
input = [1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0]

output = []
for i in input:
    if i == 0:
        output.insert(0, i)
    elif i == 2:
        output.append(i)
    else:
        if output.count(2) > 0:
            index = output.insert(output.index(2), i)
        else:
            output.append(i)

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes O(n):

```
def sort_Colors(arr):
    first = 0
    mid = 0
    last = len(arr)-1
    while mid <= last:
        if arr[mid] == 0:
            arr[first] , arr[mid] = arr[mid], arr[first]
            first += 1
            mid += 1
        elif arr[mid] == 1:
            mid += 1
        else:
            arr[mid], arr[last] = arr[last], arr[mid]
            last -= 1
    return arr
```

Input = [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Output = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]